# Is it possible to implement AlternateTypeRules functionallity with annotation?

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

I've got following issue - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2373 and I fixed it with the following code:

```
@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .alternateTypeRules(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(TestCarResource.Car.Id.class, String.class));
}
```

Can I mark my `Car.Id` class with any annotation to remove this boilerplate code?